# How self[:name] works rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I created a reader method in my users model

```
def name
self[:name]
end
```

I'm having a hard time understanding self[:name]
it looks like I'm accessing a value with a key in a Hash
 but from what i can tell its not a Hash. 
I have also tried to create classes in ruby to emulate this but cant get them to work so i"m not sure whether this is ruby or rails thing that I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord supplies a [`[]` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> **`[](attr_name)`**
>   Returns the value of the attribute identified by `attr_name` after it has been typecast...

So saying `self[:name]` is just a round-about way to access the `name` attribute of your model.

`[]` is a method like any other in Ruby, you can define your own in any class you want:

```
class C
  def [](k)
    # do whatever you want
  end
end
c = C.new
c[:pancakes]
```

ActiveRecord is used with data that is, more or less, a Hash backed by a relational database so saying `model[:attribute_name]` is fairly natural. Hence the existence of the `[]` method.